# Is it possible to extend memory for ubuntu OS?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8, ram

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTE in my DELL laptop.It is working properly,Now I can access 2 Operating systems(win8 & Ubuntu). At the time of installation process I allocated memory as around 10 GB for ubuntu.Now I want to expand memory size for ubuntu os.**How can I expand or extend memory for Ubuntu OS?**
Suggest me piece of information.
Thank you.

Comment: I think you want is to resize the partitions on your hard drive. Boot your computer from the Ubuntu installation DVD or USB stick, and choose "Try Ubuntu" (instead of "Install"). There is a graphical Disk utility that will allow you to resize the partitions on your hard drive. Apply your changes, and then reboot back into your normal system.

Comment: If I am using 10 GB for UBUNTU Os is it possible to extend up to 100gb?
are the files will be safe or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have free space on the hard drive directly after your Ubuntu partition then you can extend it as much as you have space.  Your files will be safe, however, it's always a must to backup your data before doing any operation with your partitions.  A wrong key stroke could be disastrous.

If you don't have space behind your Ubuntu partition, and you have another partition there, you'll need to use a 3rd party application which will let you shrink and grow your partitions.

I've used EaseUs Partition Manager on windows servers before with good success.  I don't know much about the product other than what worked for me.  Your mileage may vary.

[EaseUs Partition Manager](http://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-free.html)

Comment: can u explain me little bit clear..
i.e my unallocated size is around 32GB
and my current ubuntu using 7GB, How to extend partition(memory) for UBUNTU?